# I am started feeling or I have started feeling

Tags: sentence-construction

a) Now I am started feeling dizzy.

b) Now I have started feeling dizzy.

Which one is correct to say for present situation?

1 Now I am feeling good.

2 Now I am started feeling good.

3 Now I have started feeling good

Comment: Neither. Idiomatically, [it's *He felt **dizzy***, not *He felt **dizziness***.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=He+felt+dizzy%2CHe+felt+dizziness&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHe%20felt%20dizzy%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: My suggestion: stop taking those tablets.

Answer (score 1):

You could say either:

> - I am feeling dizzy (you are feeling dizzy presently)
> - I have started feeling dizzy (this *can* mean you feel dizzy presently, but can also idiomatically mean that you have recently begun to feel intermittent dizzy spells)

The word "now" could be tagged onto the *end* of these, but is redundant if the statement or context makes it clear you are presently dizzy.

For your second example:

> - I feel good / I am feeling good (you feel good presently)
> - I *have* started feeling *better*. (you feel some improvement)

"I have started feeling good" is not particularly idiomatic when speaking about health. If you have only *started* something then it suggests you are not all the way there, so the word "better" is more appropriate as a comparison.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But my actual question was different . I wanted to know should I use I am started feeling or I have started feeling for present situation.

Comment: @user4084 You completely edited your question. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for answer, "I am started feeling dizzy"  is grammatically incorrect?

Comment: @user4084 Yes, it's totally wrong. You could say "I am *starting to feel* dizzy".